# MongoDB - Is it possible to compare documents through the _id field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

As the title clearly describes, I need to make comparison between documents through the auto-generated `_id` field. For example, is it possible to make a query such as "**newer/older records than the id `5e120e38c149d02d27ea750c`**" something like `greater-than`/`less-than` operations?

Something like the below one didn't do what it was expected:

```
num_apps = db.app.count_documents({"_id": {"$lt": "5e120e38c149d02d27ea750c"}})
```

p.s. Using the `PyMongo` module.

Comment: Yes you could do that !! Did you try anything ? Can you share what you've tried & where you're stuck cause this is pretty normal & straight forward - We wanted to know where the issue is ?

Comment: Please, see the updated OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, but the problem with your query is you're passing a string as input but the type of `_id` in DB is `ObjectId()`, So input should match with it. So convert it before querying DB.

If using native **mongodb driver** :

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

num_apps = db.app.count_documents({ "_id": { "$lt": ObjectId("5e120e38c149d02d27ea750c") } })
```

If using **mongoose** :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5e120e38c149d02d27ea750c');
num_apps = db.app.count_documents({ "_id": { "$lt": id } })
```

If using **pymongo** :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

num_apps = db.app.count_documents({ "_id": { "$lt": ObjectId("5e120e38c149d02d27ea750c") } })
```